# VoIP notifications the certificate subject must end with ".voip" and the device token app bundle ends with ".voip"

Tags: ios, twilio, apple-push-notifications, voip, bundle-identifier

I have error in twilio, says "VoIP notifications the certificate subject must end with ".voip" and the device token app bundle ends with ".voip".

when I check the similar questions found that solution is to change the

> " solution was BundleID+.voip"

I tried to create a bundleId ending with ".voip" in developer.apple, though id is unique  but failed to create. whenever i add .voip it does not allow me to create.

Can some me tell me how to apply the above solution.

how, where, and what i have to do to apply the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't have to create new ID. Instead ask your backend team to push Voip notification to APNS server with header field:

> apns-topic: "com.company.app.voip"

Where `com.company.app` is the registed bundle ID.

Maybe you can use below tool to test push notifications.

https://github.com/lalkrishna/Pushfy/releases

In pushfy, select push type as "voip" and App ID BundleID+".voip"

Comment: pushfy didnt work. there is no code in the github

Comment: the bundled app is available in here: https://github.com/lalkrishna/Pushfy/releases